# Getting a 400 error when posting a JSON request using Python

Tags: python, json, rest

I am trying to send a POST JSON request using Python and seem to be getting a 400 error with a parsing error. This same request works fine in Postman..I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong and appreciate any pointers.

Postman request body that works:

```
{
          "document":
        {
            "name": "TestWebiDOC_doc",
            "folderId":1112223}
}
```

Error message that I am getting from the REST Service when using Python:

```
{"error_code":"400","message":"ParseError at [row,col]:[0,1]\nMessage: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1 of \"{\\\"document\\\": {\\\"name\\\": \\\"TestWebiDOC_doc\\\", \\\"folderId\\\": \\\"1112223\\\"}}\". "}
```

Python Code Below to send the JSON request - not able to narrow down what I am doing wrong:

```
def create_document(token):
    data = {
            'document':
                {
                    'name' : 'TestWebiDOC_doc',
                    'folderId' : '1112223'}
            }
    headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
               'Accept' : 'application/json',
               'X-SAP-LogonToken' : token}
    path = _url('/documents/')
    response = requests.post(path, json=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
    print('\nURL to create document : {}'.format(path))
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print('\nUnable to create document: {}'.format(response.status_code))
    else:
        document_id = response['success']['id']
        print('\nCreated document with id : {}'.format(document_id))
        return document_id
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to type POST - corrected it now.

Comment: Can you try with just: `response = requests.post(path, json=data, headers=headers)`?

Comment: Strangely, I tried that before and it failed and it works now...I am now failing at parsing the response....{"success":{"message":"The resource of type \"Document\" with identifier \"6745515\" has been successfully created.","id":"6745515"}}

Comment: Can you edit the question with the response and what part(s) you want to parse out of it?

Comment: This is the response object and I need to get the id value.{
    "success": {
        "message": "The resource of type \"Document\" with identifier \"6745515\" has been successfully created.",
        "id": "6745515"
    }
}

Comment: Try: `response.json()['success']['id']`

Comment: Great, that worked, thank you...Let me post the final result...Can you answer the question so I can accept it ?

Comment: Ok, just did. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just need to pass the dictionary itself as an argument to `requests.post`, like this:

```
response = requests.post(path, json=data, headers=headers)
```

Then to get the ID from the response, do:

```
response.json()['success']['id']
```