# Cloud Functions with Requests return 'Could not parse JSON' error

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, google-cloud-functions

I'm running a cloud function in python to return some data from an api. The function is not executed and I have the error `{'code': 400, 'message': 'Could not parse JSON'}`.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

def my_function(request):

    url = 'https://blablabla/detailed'
    headers = {'X-Api-Key': 'XXXXXXXX',
           'content-type': 'application/json'}

    data = '{"dateRangeStart":"2020-05-10T00:00:00.000","dateRangeEnd":"2020-05-16T23:59:59.000","amountShown": "HIDE_AMOUNT","detailedFilter":{ "page":"1","pageSize":"50"}}'
    
    #req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    print(req.json())
```

how should I format my data variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a 400 error when posting a JSON request using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60748317/getting-a-400-error-when-posting-a-json-request-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your dict as your `json` argument, you don't need to specify the `content-type` headers `requests` will do it for you.

```py
import requests


def my_function(request):
    url = 'https://blablabla/detailed'
    headers = {'X-Api-Key': 'XXXXXXXX', }

    data = {"dateRangeStart": "2020-05-10T00:00:00.000", "dateRangeEnd": "2020-05-16T23:59:59.000", "amountShown": "HIDE_AMOUNT", "detailedFilter": { "page": "1", "pageSize": "50", }, }
    
    req = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    print(req.json())
```

If you do not set a `content-type` header will try to set it for you:

- When using the keyword argument `json`: it will set it to `application/json`
- When using the keyword argument `data` (and the value passed respects some criteria, most of the time you don't have to worry about it): it will set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- If both kwargs are present `data` takes priority for the header so it will be set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

I have not detailed the behaviour when the kwarg `files` is used as it would be really lengthy and is out of scope here.

[Here's the source code](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/models/#PreparedRequest.prepare_body).

Comment: can you add more explanation on the content-type things. What's happening in this case when you specify it?